# Icon click hide it's parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="cart-singel">
    <div class="div-1">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="div-2">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="cart-singel">
    <div class="div-1">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="div-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

When click i(fa-trash) it's need to hide it's parent cart-singel div.

Comment: You neglected to share the jQuery you tried that didn't work

Comment: Yes, i tried some jQuery but it was not working. I forgot to write those. But got the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.parents()` method in jQuery, like this

```
$('.fa-trash').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.cart-singel').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("i.fa-trash").on("click",function(){
    $(this).closest("div.cart-singel").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method to find parent div & [hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide that div

```js
$(".cart-singel .div-1 i").click(function() {
$(this).parents(".cart-singel").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-singel">
  <div class="div-1">
    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true">[Trash_Icon]</i>
  </div>
  <div class="div-2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cart-singel">
  <div class="div-1">
    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true">[Trash_Icon]</i>
  </div>
  <div class="div-2">
  </div>
</div>
```